# Problems with automatic_uploads TinyMCE

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce

The problem I face is that if I set the uploader as true it will send directly to the file where the images will be saved. Because of this behaviour, the image will not load that well. No image and only a border for resizing which doesn't work.

But when I attach boolean **false** to it it will load in the edit page as a complete image but when I want to send the post to the database it will respond as "cannot covert blob: Number to BLOB" and the image will not go to the folder.

With some testing, I still stumble upon this problem. I tried it using an if statement:

```
if(array_key_exists('image',$_POST)){
};
```

but that doesn't work because in the ajax method it just doesn't see it. So what am I supposed to do? Use the **false** and built a way to insert the images into the folder or using **true** but delay the procedure or send the image to the directory when something happens.

Also when I use an url image it won't be sent to the directory which is fine by me but when I adjust it with new specifications it will be sent to the folder and will not be seeable in the editor WYSIWYG.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     tinymce.init ({

        theme: 'modern',
        selector: '.add_body_structure',
        height: 1000,
        menubar: true,
        branding: false,
        toolbar: 'undo redo code | styleselect bold italic forecolor backcolor fontselect fontsizeselect | link paste | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent bullist numlist | removeformat | insert',
        plugins: 'code contextmenu print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media mediaembed template table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help autoresize noneditable', 
        contextmenu: 'paste | link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable',
        advlist_bullet_styles: 'square',
        advlist_number_styles: 'lower-alpha,lower-roman,upper-alpha,upper-roman',
        statusbar: false,
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        image_title: true, 

        automatic_uploads: true, // or false

        media_live_embeds: true,
        contextmenu: true,
        relative_urls: false,
        remove_script_host: false,
        paste_data_images: true,
        encoding: 'xml',
        invalid_elements: 'script, input, textarea, textfield, col, colgroup, caption, dir, meta, object, select, option, source, title',
        fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 30pt 32pt 34pt 36pt 38pt 40pt',
        images_upload_url: '/wysiwyg/tinymce_main/wysiwyg_one_page_version2.1/views/home/code_for_images/image_uploader.php',
        media_live_embeds: true,


        file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*, audio/*, video/*');

            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {

                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                    // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
        input.click();
        },

        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
             var xhr, formData;

             xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhr.withCredentials = false;
             xhr.open('POST', 'image_uploader.php');

             xhr.onload = function() {
                 var json;

                 if (xhr.status != 200) {
                      failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                      return;
                 }

             json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

             if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                 failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                 return;
             }

             success(json.location);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
     }
   });
});
```

**images_upload_handler** doesn't seem to do anything for me. Did I make a mistake with that function or should it do nothing in my situation.

I also use the Postacceptor.php: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/. Obviously changed that it's working for me. I rename it to **image_uploader.php.**

**EDIT:**
I have yet to find the solution but I do know that above code isn't the problem or atleast the cause of it. I can go further into that problem aswell but that will be off topic so with this no answer was found and can be closed because I don't think this will lead to anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Because of this behaviour, the image will not load that well. No image
>   and only a border for resizing which doesn't work.

What do you mean by this? It seems like this behavior may be caused by your integration itself, and not TinyMCE.

Comment: Well to be clear. At the beginning it showed just fine on the edit page but gave multiple errors. So I after trial and error I found away to show it on the home page but this action made that every picture on the edit page are invisible. I do see the corners which you can adjust but picture itself isnt visible and when you want to adjust it I see as values; NaN x NaN. This means that it doesn't recognize the image yet I see the image in the folder.

Comment: After looking into it. I adjust the automatic upload from true to false. If I do that the image is shown on the edit page with every available tool but then it doesn't get sent to the image upload folder. So there must be a way to work around that boolean. Am I right?

Comment: Well, I didn't find the correct answer for the problem but I know for sure that automatic upload has nothing to do with it.